# setMovementMethod on a fromatted string in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-alertdialog

I have string xml formatted as follow:

```
<string name="dialog_message">My Super beautiful string<a href="https://mylink.com">Click me!</a>.\n\n\n\nVersion %1$s Build %2$s</string>
```

Then I have an **AlertDialog** like this:

```
        String message = context.getString(R.string.dialog_message, "My Version Name", "3");
        AlertDialog builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialogCustom).setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_home)
                        .setMessage(message)
.create();
        builder.show();
        ((TextView)builder.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        ((TextView)builder.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

But it doesn't work (link not clickable)..it only work if I call `.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)`

Why it doesn't work? I've tried also with `.setView()` method with custom `TextView`

Comment: hi can you try this .. 

final SpannableString s = 
               new SpannableString(context.getText(R.string.dialog_message));

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000784

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809761

Comment: @MadhavAnadkat already tried not helped, not duplicate because it works only if I don't format string!

Comment: have you tried this both lines ? 

final SpannableString s = 
               new SpannableString(context.getText(R.string.dialog_message));
  Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

Comment: Yes... @MadhavAnadkat

Comment: Okay.. let me tell you what workaround you can do for now. 

final WebView message = new WebView(this);
        message.loadData(getText(R.string.dialog_message).toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");

change below lines. 

.setMessage(message)

with 

.setView(message)


also, when you do that, you also have to change the string line to. 

<string name="dialog_message">My Super beautiful string <![CDATA[<a href="https://mylink.com" target="_blank">Click me!</a>.\n\n\n\nVersion %1$s Build %2$s]]></string>

Comment: remember .. for this solution .. 

target="_blank" in string file is important.

Comment: @MadhavAnadkat not helped..

Comment: I tried this with your example, send me your code I will fix that for you.